# JavaFX image pathway issues

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I have just figured out how to unzipped a zippedfolder into the folder `EBookReader/books` from within my program (where EBookReader is my project). Now I have a /books/testbook/1.png (what was unzipped) however no matter what I do I can not get the program to display an image on that pathway.

```
System.out.println(loadedBook.returnPage());
 Image page = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(loadedBook.returnPage())); 
 ImageView imagePage = new ImageView();
 imagePage.setImage(page);
 imagePage.setFitWidth(350);
 imagePage.setFitHeight(500);
 imagePage.setPreserveRatio(true); 
 imagePage.setSmooth(true);
 imagePage.setCache(true);
 border.setCenter(imagePage);
```

`loadedBook.returnPage()` returns the string "F:\EbookReader\books\testBook\1.png" which just so happens to be the location of the image 1.png and even if I enter the string manually into the image location it still doesn't work. I heard I didn't need the `getClass()` junk but it doesn't work without that either. The only way I have gotten it to work is if I put the image in directly in `F:\EbookReader\src\ebookreader`.

EDIT: The error is that the input stream is null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream()` is expecting a location either relative to the current class, or relative to the classpath. The path you showed certainly is not relative to either of those.

I recommend using the [`Image`constructor taking a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) and doing

```
Image page = new Image(new File(loadedBook.returnPage()).toURI().toString());
```

You could also do

```
Image page = new Image(new FileInputStream(new File(loadedBook.returnPage())));
```

Comment: I eventually did it using:     File imageFile = new File(loadedBook.returnPage());
     Image page = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString()); but your way is alot neater. Thx for the help!